# How to obtain number of tables in a keyspace in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, nosql

For example, we can use

```
select count(*) from student_database;
```

to calculate the number of rows in a table.
But how do we calculate the number of tables in a keyspace?

```
DESCRIBE TABLES;
```

gives you the list of all tables in that keyspace.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT count(*) FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name='your keyspace'`

The above query will work in cassandra 3.0 and above

Comment: Can you please help me in this answer for cassandra 3.0 and above... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469341/how-do-i-retrieve-table-names-in-cassandra-using-java

Answer (score 3):

And for a Cassandra 2.x (and lower) answer:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM system.schema_columnfamilies 
    WHERE keyspace_name='your keyspace';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rows = session.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name = 'your_keyspace_name'")

print(list(rows))
```

Result:

```
[Row(count=2)]
```

Comment: Answers should mention how the code works not just provide the solution in code.

Comment: This query works only for specific versions of the Cassandra. If you're using Python, then you need to use functionality of the driver that works with different Cassandra versions