# How do I retrieve table names in Cassandra using Java?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, nosql

If is use this code in a CQL shell , I get all the names of table(s) in that keyspace.

```
DESCRIBE TABLES;
```

I want to retrieve the same data using **ResulSet** . Below is my code in Java.

```java
String query = "DESCRIBE TABLES;";

ResultSet rs = session.execute(query);
for(Row row  : rs) {
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

While session and cluster has been initialized earlier as:

```java
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
Session session = cluster.connect("keyspace_name");
```

**Or I like to know Java code to retrieve table names in a keyspace.**

Comment: `DESCRIBE` only works on the CLI.

Comment: The how to do in Java

Answer (score 7):

The schema for the system tables change between versions quite a bit. It is best to rely on drivers Metadata that will have version specific parsing built in. From the Java Driver use

```java
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
Collection<TableMetadata> tables = cluster.getMetadata()
    .getKeyspace("keyspace_name")
    .getTables(); // TableMetadata has name in getName(), along with lots of other info

// to convert to list of the names
List<String> tableNames = tables.stream()
        .map(tm -> tm.getName())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

```java
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
Iterator<TableMetadata> tm = metadata.getKeyspace("Your Keyspace").getTables().iterator();

while(tm.hasNext()){
    TableMetadata t = tm.next();
    System.out.println(t.getName());
}
```

The above code will give you table names in the passed keyspace irrespective of the cassandra version used.

Comment: `.iterator();` doesnt return a `Collection<TableMetadata>`, need to change it to Iterator

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Thanks for suggesting... I just tried to merge 2 steps into 1 and missed that part.